# Start Widget Configure Activity or AppWidgetProvider from inside of Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I want to have multiple widgets started within my app.  I do not want to have to hold down on the screen and click add widget

is this possible?

It must be possible because on my MyTouch4G the HTC sense items have this enabled such as the calendar, weather and such
Now I know that this is an overrided homescreen madew by htc, so I hesitate to wonder if this is something that they do for themselves and is not supported in android... But I do hope, this would be very crucial for my application... We have multiple size widgets, and do not want people to have to select through them in the widget screen, but instead add them from inside the main application